# Best way to implement bluetooth LE bidirectional comunication

Tags: react-native, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-gatt

Actually i have raspberry-pi using the  `bluetooth.service.generic_attribute` and a react-native app with [react-native-ble-manager](https://github.com/innoveit/react-native-ble-manager) , with this i request to the Json-based API (on the raspberry-pi server),using a **writeWithoutResponse** characteristic that let me transfer chunks of 20 bytes as [17 bytes in ascii of the json and 3 bytes of control] and then recreate all the chunks of the json on the other side while responding with the **notification/indication** characteristic an "ok" [3 bytes flag] to request for send the next chunck.

From raspberry-pi to the app i use the **notification/indication** characteristic that let me transfer chunks of 20 bytes as [17 bytes in ascii of the json and 3 bytes of control] and then recreate all the json on the other side, while answering by a **writeWithoutResponse** characteristic  an "ok" [3 bytes flag] to request for send the next chunck.

The problem with is that the transfer's rate that is too slow(like 20 seconds to transfer acii 600 characters)... So does someone have another idea to do this?

Comment: Any comment is welcome :)

Comment: Define ‘too slow’?

Comment: Sorry forgot to notify you @barny

Comment: i will try this [lz-string](https://pieroxy.net/blog/pages/lz-string/demo.html) and come back

Comment: Seems a bit of time consuming to acknowledge every chunk. Don't do that. Also consider using a higher MTU.